# How to store my items in the shopping cart even when I change to another page (JavaScript localStorage)

Tags: javascript, html, web, local-storage

I tried to add item to the cart, but when I move to other page the items in my cart is removed, how do I keep it in localStorage. So when I add item to cart and then move to the other page I can still add item to cart with the cart still filled with items from the previous page

I tried to add item to the cart, but when I move to other page the items in my cart is removed, how do I keep it in localStorage. So when I add item to cart and then move to the other page I can still add item to cart with the cart still filled with items from the previous page

I tried to add item to the cart, but when I move to other page the items in my cart is removed, how do I keep it in localStorage. So when I add item to cart and then move to the other page I can still add item to cart with the cart still filled with items from the previous page

```
`\`// cart
let cartIcon = document.querySelector('#add-to-cart');
let cart = document.querySelector('.cart');
let closeCart = document.querySelector('#close-cart');
let buttons = document.querySelector('.btn-buy');

// open cart
cartIcon.onclick = () =\> {
cart.classList.add('active');
};
// close cart
closeCart.onclick = () =\> {
cart.classList.remove('active');
};

if (document.readyState == 'loading') {
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ready)
} else {
ready();
}

function ready() {
//Remove item from cart
let removeCartButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-remove');
console.log(removeCartButtons);
for (let i = 0; i \< removeCartButtons.length; i++) {
let button = removeCartButtons\[i\];
button.addEventListener("click", removeCartItem);
}
//quantity changes
let quantityInputs = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity');
for (let i = 0; i \< quantityInputs.length; i++) {
let input = quantityInputs\[i\];
input.addEventListener("change", quantityChanged);
}
// add to cart
let addCart = document.getElementsByClassName('add-cart');
for (let i = 0; i \< addCart.length; i++) {
let button = addCart\[i\];
button.addEventListener('click', addCartClicked);
}

    let addCarts = document.getElementsByClassName('add-cart2'); 
    for (let i = 0; i < addCarts.length; i++) {
        let button = addCarts[i];
        button.addEventListener('click', addCartsClicked);
    } 
    
    buttons.classList.add('hide-btn');
    document.getElementsByClassName('btn-buy')[0]
    .addEventListener('click', buyButtonClicked);
    
    document.getElementsByClassName('clear-cart')[0]
    .addEventListener('click', clearButtonClicked);

}

function showBuyButton(total) {
if (total \> 0) {
buttons.classList.remove('hide-btn');
} else {
buttons.classList.add('hide-btn');
}
}

function buyButtonClicked() {
let cartContent = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-content')\[0\];
while (cartContent.hasChildNodes()) {
cartContent.removeChild(cartContent.firstChild);
}
alert("Your order is placed");
updateTotal();
}

function clearButtonClicked() {
let cartButtonClicked = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-content')\[0\];
while (cartButtonClicked.hasChildNodes()) {
cartButtonClicked.removeChild(cartButtonClicked.firstChild);
}
updateTotal();
}

//Remove item from cart
function removeCartItem(event) {
let  buttonClicked = event.target;
buttonClicked.parentElement.remove();
updateTotal();  
}

//quantity change
function quantityChanged(event) {
let input = event.target;
if (isNaN(input.value) || input.value \<= 0) {
input.value = 1;
}
if (isNaN(input.value) || input.value \> 20) {
alert('Max items are 20');
input.value = 20;
}
updateTotal();
}

function addCartClicked(event) {
let button = event.target;
let shopProducts = button.parentElement;
let title = shopProducts.getElementsByClassName('product-name')\[0\].innerText;
let price = shopProducts.getElementsByClassName('product-price')\[0\].innerText;
let stock = shopProducts.getElementsByClassName('product-stock')\[0\].innerText;
let productImg = shopProducts.getElementsByClassName('product-picture')\[0\].src;
console.log(title, price, stock, productImg);
addProductToCart(title, price, stock, productImg);
updateTotal();
}

function addProductToCart(title, price, stock, productImg) {
let cartShopBox = document.createElement('div');
cartShopBox.classList.add('cart-box');  
let cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-content')\[0\];
let cartItemsNames = cartItems.getElementsByClassName('cart-product-title');
for (let i = 0; i \< cartItemsNames.length; i++) {
if (cartItemsNames\[i\].innerText == title) {
alert("You have already add this item to cart");
return;
}
}
let cartBoxContent = `     <img src="${productImg }" alt="" class="cart-img">     <div class="detail-box">         <div class="cart-product-title">${title}</div>         <div class="cart-price">${price}</div>         <div class="cart-stock">${stock}</div>         <input type="number" value="1" class="cart-quantity">     </div>     <i class='bx bx-trash cart-remove'></i>`;

    cartShopBox.innerHTML = cartBoxContent;
    cartItems.append(cartShopBox);
    cartShopBox
        .getElementsByClassName('cart-remove')[0]
        .addEventListener('click', removeCartItem);
    cartShopBox
        .getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity')[0]
        .addEventListener('change', quantityChanged);

}

//update total
function updateTotal() {
let cartContent = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-content')\[0\];
let cartBoxes = cartContent.getElementsByClassName('cart-box');
let total = 0;
for (let i = 0; i \< cartBoxes.length; i++) {
let cartBox = cartBoxes\[i\];
let priceElement = cartBox.getElementsByClassName('cart-price')\[0\];
let quantityElement = cartBox.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity')\[0\];
let price = parseFloat(priceElement.innerText.replace("$",""));
let quantity = quantityElement.value;
total = total + (price \* quantity);
}
//if price contains some cents
total = Math.round(total \*100) / 100;
document.getElementsByClassName('total-price')\[0\].innerText = "$" + total;
showBuyButton(total);
}

function nameS() {
let name = document.getElementById('nameS').value;
}\``
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Answer (score 1):

save data to localstorage use

```
localStorage.setItem('key', 'value');
```

if value is not string use

```
localStorage.setItem('key', JSON.stringify(value));
```

and addEventListener to subscribe when data in localstorage change

```
window.addEventListener('storage', function(event){
  if (event.storageArea === localStorage) {
      const value = localStorage.getItem('key');
  }
}, false);
```

Comment: But I think it's better to put it in other storage for making a shopping basket.

Comment: Does the order line where to put getItem matter?